# What is the difference between get_result() and store_result() in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code. I am checking if a user exists or not in a login/registration system:

```
public function userExist($email){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select email from users where email= ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows>0){

    }
    else{

    }
}
```

Can I use get_result instead of store_result() ?

Comment: did you go over the manuals?

Comment: i did.....get_result() returns a result set from prepared statements, but so does store_result()

Comment: Which database driver are you using?

Comment: `get_result()` is to get and `store_result()` is to put

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It depends on how you plan to read the result set. But in the actual example you have given, you are not interested in reading any returned data. The only thing that interests you is whether there is a record or not.

In that case your code is fine, but it would work equally well with *get_result*.

The difference becomes more apparent, when you want to get for example the *userid* of the user with the given email:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?
```

If you plan to read out that *id* with `$stmt->fetch`, then you would stick to 
`store_result`, and would use `bind_result` to define in which variable you want to get this *id*, like this:

```
$stmt->store_result();    
$stmt->bind_result($userid);  // number of arguments must match columns in SELECT
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $userid;  
    }
}
```

If you prefer to get a result object on which you can call `fetch_assoc()` or any of the fetch_* variant methods, then you need to use `get_result`, like this:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();   // You get a result object now
if($result->num_rows > 0) {     // Note: change to $result->...!
    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $data['id'];
    }
}
```

Note that you get a result object from `get_result`, which is not the case with `store_result`. You should get `num_rows` from that result object now.

Both ways work, and it is really a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 11):

As usual, the accepted answer is too localized, being much more focused on the insignificant details than on the answer itself.

There is also, sadly, a deleted answer, which, although being laconic, makes a perfect rule of thumb:

> Use get_result whenever possible and store_result elsewhere.

Both functions load the pending resultset from the database to PHP process' memory, with `get_result()` being much more versatile and therefore preferred.

The only difference between `get_result()` and `store_result()` is that the former *gets* you a familiar [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) resource/object which can be used to fetch the data using familiar `fetch_row()` / `fetch_assoc()` routines, as well as a slightly modern [fetch_all()](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/select#fetch_all), all of those being incomparably more convenient than `bind_result()` routine which is the only option with `store_result()`.

It could be noted that `get_result()` is only available when mysqlnd driver is used, which is not an issue in 2019 and beyond. If it's not available, you are probably to tick some checkbox in your shared host's configuration.